# How does a Unix program know to change output if it's being piped?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, pipe

Calling something like `ag` (a `grep` alternative) results in an output that's human readable. Results are printed with headers. Useful for humans, horrible for programs.

```bsh
$ ag 'filter\('
tests/string_lookup/tests.py
75:        self.assertSequenceEqual(Article.objects.filter(submitted_from__contains='192.0.2'), [a])
77:        self.assertEqual(Article.objects.filter(submitted_from__contains='32').count(), 0)

tests/test_runner/test_debug_sql.py
16:            Person.objects.filter(first_name='pass').count()
20:            Person.objects.filter(first_name='fail').count()
```

Same program, piped into something else, outputs:

```bsh
$ ag 'filter\(' | cat
tests/string_lookup/tests.py:75:        self.assertSequenceEqual(Article.objects.filter(submitted_from__contains='192.0.2'), [a])
tests/string_lookup/tests.py:77:        self.assertEqual(Article.objects.filter(submitted_from__contains='32').count(), 0)
tests/test_runner/test_debug_sql.py:16:            Person.objects.filter(first_name='pass').count()
tests/test_runner/test_debug_sql.py:20:            Person.objects.filter(first_name='fail').count()
```

This output is much better suited for use by other programs, so I assume that `ag` is aware that it's being piped.

How is `ag` aware of where it's output is being sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program calls `isatty()` on the stdout file descriptor (i.e. `1`). If the function returns true, the output is connected to a tty device (a terminal).

Comment: Right on the money! I wasn't even sure where to start looking. And here it is in the source of the program: https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/5a1c8d83ba1514ca8d045ba80403f93772fb371a/src/options.c#L369